# update the part of HTML text inside DIV using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="Test">
 name - date   //First name ,Last name - 7/24/2013
 <button type="button"/>
```

How do i update the part of HTML text inside DIV using Jquery.

I need to update the date section alone inside the div. What i tried is like having the date section in a `span with class name` and update the text.

But there must be a way to update the `text without having <span>` .

Am looking for a fix without using

Thanks

Comment: I doubt there is. The only way without wrapping the date inside another element is to update all the text inside div.Test

Comment: Do you only want to update the date? Leave the name as is?

Comment: You can use a regex expression but that would be an overkill. Using an extra element wrapping it and targeting is the simplest among all

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you a bit of different way, using regular expression. (Although probably the best way is to use an extra span element.)

```
var testPattern = /date/;
var divToTest = $('.Test').html();

divToTest = divToTest.replace(divToTest.match(testPattern),'yourDate');
$('.Test').html(divToTest);
```

Also keep in mind, that if the date is for example dd.mm.yyyy format , you just need to change your reg exp for the specific format.
Hope that helped :). (EDITED: Thanks to  @Geoff Appleford)

Comment: This works but you need to put the changed html back into the div: `$('.Test').html(divToTest);`

Comment: @Geoff Appleford Thanks for the catch.(EDITED) :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a way but i really suggest you to use extra span element.

Create function that fills your div with text

```
function fillDiv(date) {
    var html = 'Your text here and after that put ' + date;
    $('#myDiv').html(html);
}
```

And call this function on page load and on every next change.

Comment: This causes the `button` to be lost

Comment: Sure, but its not a big deal to avoid that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var node = document.createTextNode("asdf");
$($('.Test').contents().get(0)).replaceWith(node)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SjjDq/)

Answer (score 0):

If your content has exactly structure like name - date, so you can split your content by - and then replace the second item in your array. Finally you can merge items into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what Phong said, the code to do so would look something like:

```
var children = $('.Test').children();
$('.Test').html($('.Test').html().split('-')[0] + '- ' + newDate).append(children);
```

That said, this should only be used if for some reason you can't wrap the date in a `span`.

Comment: But then you're losing a `button`

Comment: Oops, you're right, I didn't see the button. My last edit should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var dateTxt = $('.Test').text().split('-');
$('.Test').text(dateTxt[0] + ' - date');
```